# chromeWebdriver - unable to set cookie when I update Chrome to 77

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I update my Chrome and chromewebdriver to version 77. After this I have an error (`unable to set cookie`) when I `addCookie`.

```
System.setProperty("cookie", "auth=ok,path=/");
int indexValue = cookieStr.indexOf('=');
int indexPath = cookieStr.indexOf(",path=");
String cookieName = cookieStr.substring(0, indexValue);
String cookieValue = cookieStr.substring(indexValue + 1, indexPath);
String cookieDomain = new URI("http://localhost").getHost().replaceAll("self.", "");
String cookiePath = cookieStr.substring(indexPath + 6);
Cookie authCookie= new Cookie.Builder(cookieName, cookieValue).domain(cookieDomain).path(cookiePath).expiresOn(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("31/12/2020")).build();
System.out.println("A");
driver.navigate().to("http://localhost:8000/unprotected");
System.out.println("B");
driver.get("http://localhost:8000/404");
System.out.println("C");
System.out.println("[" + driver.getPageSource()+"]");
Options b = a.manage();
System.out.println("Domain: " + cookie.getDomain());
System.out.println("Name: " + cookie.getName());
System.out.println("Path: " + cookie.getPath());
System.out.println("Value: " + cookie.getValue());
System.out.println("Expiry: " + cookie.getExpiry());
b.addCookie(cookie);   <= KO
System.out.println("D");
```

**Console:**

```
A
B
C
[<html><head></head><body><h1>404 Not Found</h1>No context found for request</body></html>]
Domain: localhost
Name: auth
Path: /
Value: ok
Expiry: Thu Dec 31 00:00:00 CET 2020
```

**Error:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnableToSetCookieException: unable to set cookie
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.75)
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T14:04:26.12Z'
System info: host: 'xxxxxxxxx', ip: '192.168.0.111', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 77.0.3865.75, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0..., userDataDir: C:\Users\JFTS8586\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:58344}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: accept}
Session ID: 82305922f96631ac61d95a737263cb64]
```

**Full code is present on line** [here](https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi-POC/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/noraui/sof/AddCookieTest.java) (in one class) if you want reproduce this problem on your local machine.

More informations from chromium team [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3135).

Comment: can you try with 127.0.0.1 instead of loclahost ?

Comment: It looks related to the [CORS policy](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/site-isolation). Try these switches: `--disable-web-security --disable-features=CrossSiteDocumentBlockingIfIsolating`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

Setting  a domain cookie on local host is no longer supported by Chrome. If you remove the domain from the cookie settings, it should work correctly.

More details:

The current WebDriver standard isn't clear on how cookie domain should be handled. ChromeDriver's implementation attempts to follow https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.3. According to item 6 of the cookie storage model, specifying a cookie domain results in a domain cookie, while not specifying the domain results in a host-only cookie. However, creating a domain cookie for localhost doesn't really make sense, as localhost doesn't following the domain naming conventions. Chrome used to be lenient with this, but Chrome 77 now has code to reject creating domain cookie for localhost, so specifying domain for localhost cookie is no longer allowed.